# Correct order of attaching Observer when Starting Background Task

Tags: kotlin, android-livedata, observers

In a fragment or an activity, is there a recommended order to setting the observer vs initiating the data producer?

For example, assuming no others are fetching data or observing, then:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
 ): View? {

    // OPTION A: this seems bullet-proof. Setup the observer first, 
    //  then trigger the generation of the data...
    // ----------------------------------------------------------
    // 1) setup observer
    mainViewModel.myResponse.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { response -> {...} })

    // 2) initiate data fetching
    mainViewModel.generateFetchInBackground()

    // OPTION B: this is what I sometimes see done. This seems like
    //   a race condition since the triggering of generation happens
    //   first, then the observer is established...
    // ----------------------------------------------------------
    // 1) initiate data fetching
    mainViewModel.generateFetchInBackground()        
    
    // 2) setup observer
    mainViewModel.myResponse.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { response -> {...} })

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't mater when you start providing data or observing it. `LiveData` guaranties all the values will be delivered to your observers when they [become active](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#work_livedata).

> When you update the value stored in the LiveData object, it triggers all registered observers as long as the attached LifecycleOwner is in the active state.
> LiveData allows UI controller observers to subscribe to updates. When the data held by the LiveData object changes, the UI automatically updates in response.

That's why `LiveData` help you decouple producer and observers. And there is no race condition on `LiveData` because it delivers all of the data on the main thread.